# Browser content  control became empty when back button pressed from external browser(Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

In my application I am using a WebBrowserTask for navigating to some links in external web browser. But when I click back button the content of my web browser control became empty, also I set this content.

```
 WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();
                webBrowserTask.URL = e.Uri.ToString();
                webBrowserTask.Show();
```

*UPDATE*

When I test on emulator the content is not empty, but when I test it on real device it becomes empty

Comment: Youre Problem is unclear to me, please provide more/precise Informations. (Like a Workflow)

Comment: Also, what web browser *control*, as you're starting a WebBrowser *task*

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the URL you provided is an attachment like .pdf or .ppt. Most of the time you will see the attached files getting opened, so after opening and hitting a back button you will see a screen something like below. But I do remember seeing blank screen at times cannot attribute the reason. Can you please share what link you are trying to open to look deeper. It has nothing to do with your code. It is how the Webbrowser behaves.

[image]